# Why the preempt_count is not the per cpu variable in old version linux kernel like 2.6.33

Tags: linux, kernel, interrupt, pic, preemptive

I have question about the preemptive_count in the old linux kernel (e.g. 2.6.33)

```
    #define preempt_count() (current_thread_info()->preempt_count)
```

all the related field in this variable is about the CPU related info, why the kernel does not using a cpu based variable?